# Chrome flash crash issue

Tags: php, javascript, flash, google-chrome, shockwave

In my website have a flash player, it is working in all browsers expect latest version of Chrome. In latest version of chrome it shows crash, because in latest version of Chrome (Chrome 22), they add 'experimental' **PepperFlash plugin** the default player for Flash content and removed the old integrated Chrome Flash plugin, ([please check this](http://techlogon.com/2011/08/11/shockwave-flash-crashes-in-google-chrome/)) , I want to disable **PepperFlash ** plugin using php script/javascript/jquery, please help

Comment: There is no way You can modify clients' browser settings

Comment: then how can inform Chrome users about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.

What you can do is that you can change your flash code. Assuming it is [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155437), you could work around it by calling Camera#setMode with different resolution parameters, like advised in that thread. The thread says that these resolution parameters will cause the issue:

> 320x240
>   640x480
>   1024x768
>   1152x864
>   1280x720
>   1280x768
>   1280x960
>   1280x1024
>   1920x1080

whereas if you change the param even for one pixel, it would work.

There might be other bugs there too (at least there are some open issues) - you could advise end user with chrome to disable pepperflash, if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [here is an intersting short article](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108086) about Flash.

And [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSFxb/2/) to detect PepperFlash.
Fact is that you cannot disable the usage of the plugin PeeperFlash from the client-side.
For this you would need far more rights than your browser will give you.

Only way is to disable it using the plugin settings of chrome.